# PyQt QFileInfo error

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am working on an app in PyQt and when trying to get the QFileInfo from a user-selected file I get the error

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
QFileInfo(): too many arguments
QFileInfo(str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'tuple'
QFileInfo(QFile): argument 1 has unexpected type 'tuple'
QFileInfo(QDir, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'tuple'
QFileInfo(QFileInfo): argument 1 has unexpected type 'tuple'
Abort trap: 6
```

I have followed every tutorial to a tee, yet this error keeps on happening. 
My code is below, and I am only passing a string into the module. I don't know what I need to do.

```
    def __init__(self, r, c):
        super().__init__(r, c)
        self.check_change = True
        self.path = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,'Open File',os.getenv('Home'), 'CSV(*.csv)')        
        file_info = QFileInfo(self.path)
        file_name = file_info.fileName()
        #print(file_name)
        self.init_ui()
```

Comment: "argument 1 has unexpected type 'tuple'" Basically the error message tells you the problem. Next step would be to read documentation of `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName` returns a tuple. To get just the path to the file it looks like you need to do something like the example below -- where `_` is just a placeholder (please see example here: https://pythonspot.com/en/pyqt5-file-dialog/).

```
self.path, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,'Open File',os.getenv('Home'), 'CSV(*.csv)')
```

Comment: Another easy thing to do is just take the first value of the tuple. So OP can just use self.path[0] to get the path.